# Is Software versioning and software data versioning the same or different?

Tags: database, architecture, export, versioning

I'm wondering if Software versioning and software data versioning are the same or different ? 
Let me explain by an example :

I develop a software that is versioned like this v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2...
This software provides data exporting as "export project...".

My question is : Does my "project entity" have to manage is own versioning system like v1, v2, v3...
or Does my "project entity" have to simply know for which version of the software he is made for.

Does Datas of a software have to manage its own versioning to be able to program data application upgrader or not ?

Thanks a lot,